# UICollectionView em 2 colunas

Tags: swift, xcode

Amigos, tenho uma `IUCollectionView` que esta apresentando dos dados em 3 colunas, como eu poderia fazer para mostrar apenas 2 com uma imagem centralizada?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Tem como você postar um exemplo do resultado esperado? Não entendi essa parte de imagem centralizada.

Answer (score 1):

Para que O `UICollectionView` apresente as células como espera, você tem duas opções:

1. Aumentar o tamanho da sua célula; ou
2. Aumentar os espaços entre suas células e as bordas.

**1) Aumentar o tamanho da sua célula**

Nesse caso, você pode simplesmente alterar o tamanho da célula no `UIStoryboard` (maneira mais fácil/rápida); ou declarar explicitamente o `CGSize` que você espera que a célula tenha implementando o método `collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGSize` (do `UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout`)

**2) Aumentar os espaços entre suas células e as bordas**

Nesse caso, você pode implementar os métodos do protocolo `UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout` referentes a isso, como:

- `collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, insetForSectionAtIndex section: Int) -> UIEdgeInsets`
- `collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, minimumInteritemSpacingForSectionAtIndex section: Int) -> CGFloat`
- `collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, minimumLineSpacingForSectionAtIndex section: Int) -> CGFloat`

**Hands-on**

Suponhamos que você queira que a célula tenha a dimensão de 100px de largura por 100px de altura com *padding* de 20px entre as bordas e o meio. A implementação ficará (mais ou menos) assim (não testado):

**Swift 2**

```
let cellDimension : CGFloat = 100
let spaceBetweenCells : CGFloat = 20
let numberOfColumns : CGFloat = 2

....

// Layout
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGSize {
    return CGSize(width: cellDimension, height: cellDimension)
}

func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, insetForSectionAtIndex section: Int) -> UIEdgeInsets {
    let width = self.view.frame.width
    let expectUsedSize : CGFloat = (cellDimension * numberOfColumns) + spaceBetweenCells
    let margins = (width - expectUsedSize) / numberOfColumns
    return UIEdgeInsetsMake(spaceBetweenCells, margins, spaceBetweenCells, margins)
}

func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, minimumInteritemSpacingForSectionAtIndex section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    return spaceBetweenCells
}

func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, minimumLineSpacingForSectionAtIndex section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    return spaceBetweenCells
}
```

**Swift 3**

```
// Layout
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
    return CGSize(width: cellDimension, height: cellDimension)
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, insetForSectionAt section: Int) -> UIEdgeInsets {
    let width = self.view.frame.width
    let expectUsedSize : CGFloat = (cellDimension * numberOfColumns) + spaceBetweenCells
    let margins = (width - expectUsedSize) / numberOfColumns
    return UIEdgeInsetsMake(spaceBetweenCells, margins, spaceBetweenCells, margins)
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, minimumInteritemSpacingForSectionAt section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    return spaceBetweenCells
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, minimumLineSpacingForSectionAt section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    return spaceBetweenCells
}
```

**Nota**

No código acima usei o mesmo espaço entre as células (`spaceBetweenCells`) para o `UIEdgeInsets` da célula (bottom e top). Você pode (obviamente) alterar esse valor como quiser.

Abs!

**Obs.:** A implementação acima tem o objetivo de ilustrar o algoritmo que calcula o tamanho certo da célula para diferentes larguras de aparelhos (iPhone 4s/5/5c/5s/6/6s/7/7s ou iPads);